# Use method as event listener instead of class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I always make an event listener for buttons and such like this:

```
class MyClass implements extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

      JButton btn1, btn2, btn3;      

      public Myclass(){
            ....
            btn1 = new JButton("button 1");
            btn1.addActionListener(this);
            ....
      }

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Object action = e.getSource();
            if(action = btn1){
                functionForBTN1();
            }
            else if(action = btn2){
                functionForBTN2();
            }
            else if(action = btn3){
                functionForBTN3();
            }

      }

      public void functionForBTN1(){...}
      public void functionForBTN2(){...}
      public void functionForBTN3(){...}

}
```

Is it possible to direct the event directly to a method instead of the `actionPerformed()` method? something like (pseudo-code):

```
class MyClass implements extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

          JButton btn1, btn2, btn3;      

          public Myclass(){
                ....
                btn1 = new JButton("button 1");
                btn1.addActionListener(this.functionForBTN1());
                ....
          }

          public void functionForBTN1(){...}
          public void functionForBTN2(){...}
          public void functionForBTN3(){...}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Java 8, you can accomplish this using a lambda expression.

```
btn1.addActionListener(e -> this.functionForBTN1());
```

Prior to Java 8, you could create an anonymous ActionListener to acomplish the same task.

```
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        this.functionForBTN1();
    }
});
```

Comment: great answer exactly where I was looking for. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use anonymous classes:

```
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {      
         // ....
     }
});
```

However, if you want to add it like you did in your second snippet, you can do something like:

```
final ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btn1) {
            //...
        } else if (e.getSource() == btn2) {
            //...        
        }
    }
};
```

And then:

```
btn1.addActionListener(listener);
btn2.addActionListener(listener);
```

I personally prefer anonymous classes as long as they're readable and not too long.

Answer (score 1):

As Maroun Maroun said an anonymous class is a good idea. With java-8 you could also use a lamdba which makes the code slightly nicer;

```
btn1.addActionListener(event -> functionForBTN1());
```

Comment: (Nit: lambda's are still based on classes, just another step hidden from more wordy anonymous classes.)

Comment: @user2864740 I know, even if its more than syntatic sugar for anonymous classes!